# Position banner to right of logo in header - messed up my header file

Tags: php, html

Hi I made a mistake by editing my `header.php` file before backing it up and now having trouble getting it right. There's just a `<div>` tag missing or something but I am spinning my wheels so maybe someone can help me. Here is what the header looks like now. You'll see the logo is dropping beneath the menu. I need it to be above it like it was originally and a banner added positioned to left of the logo.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(' - ', true, 'left'); ?></title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>


<!-- STYLESHEET
================================================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />


<!-- GOOGLE FONTS
================================================== -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<!-- COSTUM STYLE
================================================== -->
<?php global $data; ?>
<style type="text/css">
        <?php if ($data ['custom_bg']): ?> body { background-image : url(<?php echo $data ['custom_bg']; ?>); background-repeat: repeat;} <?php endif; ?>

        .nav-pages li a:hover, .social-box li a:hover, .searchlink:hover, .searchlink.open, #search button:hover, .scrollbox li:hover .spt a, .scrollbox li p, .scrollbox li p a, .title-main-scroll-i a:hover, .title-main-i a:hover, .box-a-1:hover li .ba1-pt a, .box-a-1 li .date, .box-a-1 li .date a, .box-a-2 li:hover a, .box-a-2 li .date, .box-z li:hover .bza a, .box-b-1 li:hover .ba1-pt a, .box-b-1 li .date, .box-b-1 li .date a, .box-b-2 li:hover a, .box-b-2 li p, .box-b-3 li:hover a, .box-b-3 li p, .title-main2-i a:hover, .box-c-1-1 li:hover .ba1-pt a, .box-c-1-1 li p, .box-c-1-1 li p a, .box-c-1-2 li:hover a, .box-c-1-2 li p, .tabsContainer ul.tabs li.active, .box-tab-single li:hover a, .box-tab-single li p, .tags-cloud li a:hover, .social-footer li a:hover, .footer-copyright a:hover, .footer-box li:hover a, .footer-box .comment-author-link a:hover, .footer-box li, .backontop a:hover, .box-r-1 li:hover .ba1-pt a, .box-r-1 li .date, .box-r-1 li .date a, .pagenavi a:hover, .pagenavi span, #nav-pages li a:hover, .reply, .reply  a, .reply  a:hover, #b-news li a:hover, .breaking-news .random  a:hover, .featured .scrolling-block li:hover h3 a, .featured .scrolling-block li .date a:hover, .box-a-one .field .date a:hover, .box-a-one:hover .field h3 a, .box-a-two .field:hover h3 a, .box-a-two .field .date a:hover, .main-widget .scrolling-block li:hover h3 a, .main-widget .scrolling-block li .date a:hover, .box-b-one .field:hover h3 a, .box-b-one .field .date a:hover, .box-b-two .field:hover h3 a, .box-b-two .field .date a:hover, .box-b-three .field:hover h3 a, .box-b-three .field .date a:hover, .box-c-two .field:hover h3 a, .box-c-two .field .date a:hover, .box-c-three .field:hover h3 a, .box-c-three .field .date a:hover, .s-widget .scrolling-block li:hover h3 a, .s-widget .scrolling-block li .date a:hover, .archive-one .field .date a:hover, .archive-one .field:hover h3 a, .box-tab-one .field:hover h3 a, .box-tab-one .field .date a:hover { color: <?php echo $data ['main_color']; ?>; }

        .menu-header ul li.current_page_item > a, .menu-header ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a, .menu-header ul li.current-menu-item > a, .menu-header ul li.current-menu-parent > a, .breaking-news h3, .cat-box-title h2:hover, .allpost:hover, .s-widget #search button  { background: <?php echo $data ['main_color']; ?>; }

        .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover, .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover, .jcarousel-prev:hover, .jcarousel-next:hover, .title-sidebar-inner-f {         background: <?php echo $data ['main_color']; ?>; }

        .title-main, .title-main-i, .title-mainr, .title-mainr-i, .title-main2, .title-main2-i, .title-main-scroll, .title-main-scroll-i, .sidebar-title, .sidebar-title-inner { border-top:2px solid <?php echo $data ['main_color']; ?>; }

        .footer-big { border-top:3px solid <?php echo $data ['main_color']; ?>; }

        .s-widget #search button { border:1px solid <?php echo $data ['main_color']; ?>; }

        a:hover { color: <?php echo $data ['main_color']; ?>; }

        ::selection { background: <?php echo $data ['main_color']; ?>; }
        ::-moz-selection { background: <?php echo $data ['main_color']; ?>; }

        .footer-big { background: <?php echo $data ['footer_background']; ?>; }

        .footer-inner { background : <?php echo $data ['footer_font_color']; ?>; }        
</style>


<!-- Java Script
================================================== -->


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/modernizr.custom.79639.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/ontop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/icons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/demo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/ticker.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
$(document).ready(function() {
if ( $("#b-news").length > 0 ) { 
        var options = {
                newsList: "#b-news",
                startDelay: 10,
                loopDelay: 5000,
                placeHolder1: ""
        };


        $().newsTicker(options);
        }
        $(".close_mess").click(function () {
                $("#message").remove();
        });
});
})(jQuery);
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
</script>


<script defer src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script defer src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


(function()
{var po = document.createElement("script");
po.type = "text/javascript"; po.async = true;po.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();


</script>


<script type="text/javascript">


        $('.tabsContainer').ready(function(e) {
                $(this).find('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
                        var index = $(this).index();
                        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).parent('.tabs').siblings('.tabcontent').removeClass('active').eq(index).addClass('active');     
                });
        });


</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var $searchlink = $('#searchlink');


  $searchlink.on('click', function(e){
    var target = e ? e.target : window.event.srcElement;

    if($(target).attr('id') == 'searchlink') {
      if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('open');
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>


<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="top-inner">
                <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Top Menu') ) : ?><?php endif; ?>

                <div class="social-box">


                        <ul class="cf">

                        <?php if ($data ['s_on_t_switch']): ?>
                                        <?php echo $data ['s_on_t_switch']; ?>
                                <li class="searchlink" id="searchlink"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                        <div class="searchformm">
                                        <form id="search" action="" name="s">
                                        <input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="Looking For..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
                                        <button type="submit" class="sbtn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                        </form>
                                        </div>
                                </li>
                                <?php endif; ?>        

                                <?php if ($data ['rss_icon_switch']): ?>
                                        <?php echo $data ['rss_icon_switch']; ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php global $data; echo $data ['rss_icon_link']; ?>" title="RSS" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>        

                                <?php if ($data ['instagram_icon_switch']): ?>
                                        <?php echo $data ['instagram_icon_switch']; ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php global $data; echo $data ['instagram_icon_link']; ?>" title="Intagram" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>        

                                <?php if ($data ['youtube_icon_switch']): ?>
                                        <?php echo $data ['youtube_icon_switch']; ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php global $data; echo $data ['youtube_icon_link']; ?>" title="YouTube" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>        

                                <?php if ($data ['tumblr_icon_switch']): ?>
                                        <?php echo $data ['tumblr_icon_switch']; ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php global $data; echo $data ['tumblr_icon_link']; ?>" title="Tumblr" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>        

                                <?php if ($data ['pinterest_icon_switch']): ?>
                                        <?php echo $data ['pinterest_icon_switch']; ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php global $data; echo $data ['pinterest_icon_link']; ?>" title="Pinterest" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>        

                                <?php if ($data ['linkedin_icon_switch']): ?>
                                        <?php echo $data ['linkedin_icon_switch']; ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php global $data; echo $data ['linkedin_icon_link']; ?>" title="LinkedIn" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($data ['gplus_icon_switch']): ?>
                                        <?php echo $data ['gplus_icon_switch']; ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php global $data; echo $data ['gplus_icon_link']; ?>" title="Google +" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($data ['tw_icon_switch']): ?>
                                        <?php echo $data ['tw_icon_switch']; ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php global $data; echo $data ['tw_icon_link']; ?>" title="Twitter" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($data ['fb_icon_switch']): ?>
                                        <?php echo $data ['fb_icon_switch']; ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php global $data; echo $data ['fb_icon_link']; ?>" title="Facebook" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>        

                        </ul> 
                </div>
        </div>        


  <div class="logo">
        <div class="header-inner">
                <span class="logo">
                        <?php if ($data['logo']): ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><img src="<?php echo $data['logo']; ?>" alt="logo" /></a>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                </span>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navigation-inner"><?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Main Menu') ) : ?><?php endif; ?></div>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: justgoodnewsonly.com It wouyldn't let me post the URL for some reason??

Comment: Since this is a paid theme, can't you just download it from the theme's repository and compare the `header.php` files?

Comment: Other than that you can check a [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.justgoodnewsonly.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). It's a good start.